# Change values in pandas dataframe depending on value to subset of value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where some of the values are empty lists, and others are lists of dicts. like this:

```
0   [{'text': 'Improvement in steam-engine side-va...   []  []  [{'text': '@einen tetes strut ffice. IMPROV...
1   [{'text': 'Gate.', 'language': 'en', 'truncate...   []  []  [{'text': 'No. 645,359. Patented Mar. 13, I900...
2   [{'text': 'Overseaming sewing-machine.', 'lang...   []  []  [{'text': 'No. 64 5,8l5. Patented Mar. 20, I90...
```

I want to change the values where they are lists of dicts to be just one value from the first dict of the list.
I would have liked to do something like this:

```
df.loc[df!=[]] = df[0]['text']
```

Which obviously doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, given this toy dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [
            [{"text": "Improvement ..."}],
            [],
            [],
            [{"text": "@einen tete..."}],
        ],
        [
            [{"text": "Overseaming..."}],
            [],
            [],
            [{"text": "No. 64 5,8l5..."}],
        ],
    ]
)
print(df)
# Outputs
                               0   1   2                              3
0  [{'text': 'Improvement ...'}]  []  []   [{'text': '@einen tete...'}]
1   [{'text': 'Overseaming...'}]  []  []  [{'text': 'No. 64 5,8l5...'}]
```

You could do this:

```py
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x[0]["text"] if x != [] else x)

print(df)
# Ouputs
                 0   1   2                3
0  Improvement ...  []  []   @einen tete...
1   Overseaming...  []  []  No. 64 5,8l5...
```

Alternatively, you could iterate and update values like this:

```py
for col in df.columns:
    for i in df.index:
        try:
            df.loc[i, col] = df.loc[i, col][0]["text"]
        except IndexError:
            continue

print(df)
# Ouputs
                 0   1   2                3
0  Improvement ...  []  []   @einen tete...
1   Overseaming...  []  []  No. 64 5,8l5...
```

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping there was some dataframe functionality I could use to do this a bit simpler..

Comment: I've edited my answer to achieve the desired result only using Pandas functionnalities (as for being simpler...).

Comment: cool! apply is a great idea. in that case it would be simpler to use one function for the whole dataframe, no? I'll put it in a second answer because i don't know how to add code to a comment :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but It makes me realize there's a much cleaner way to do this with Pandas, see my updated answer.

Comment: exactly, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

improving Laurent's great answer, solving the problem in one line using dataframe functionality:

```
df.applymap(lambda x:x[0]["text"] if x!=[])
```